# Half vs. Full-Bridge

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics

What are the big differences between a Half and a Full Bridge for a controlled voltage source? I know that by the Half Bridge implementation, bus pumping of the voltage source occure, which doesn't happen in a Full Bridge. But in the Full Bridge there is no defined potential. So are there other differences i don't see?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9arHU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Half Bridge-------------------------------------------------------------Full Bridge

Edit: with no diffined potenial, i ment there is a common mode. sorry english is not my native language.

Comment: I don't see an undefined potential in H bridge.

Comment: This smells too much like homework, after a slight rewording.  It's also not clear what exactly you are asking about, and the comment of *"no defined potential"* makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full bridge setup will let you have an output voltage range going from  v3 - v4 (2 volts here) to -(v3-v4) (-2 volts here)

A half bridge setup will only let you have half that range, i.e. from 1 to -1 volts

This is because is a full bridge, as opposed to a half bridge, the output voltage is not referenced to ground, but rather one of v3 or v4.